# weird string behavior after reading from text file in python

Tags: python, text-files

I am reading a text file which I know its 38th line is "Uncalibrated Peaks:", and I know its stored in 38th element of my list. I already check them and there is no indexing problem.

I am reading the text file by the following code

```
import os

fd = open('Report.txt')
contents = fd.readlines()
fd.close()

for ind, line in enumerate(contents):
    line = line.split(" ")
    contents[ind] = line
```

but we I check for instance length of first word in the 38th line by

```
print len(contents[38][0])
```

25, I know that this command is mention to the correct element in the list, so there is no indexing issue

```
print len('Uncalibrated')
```

12

!! although in theory their should be same. seems each character takes 2 place in the string vector, which seems is beause of unicodeing issue

Comment: I hope that you actually tried `print contents[38][0]` before asking this.

Comment: I just wrote the number to make it clear for those who don't read questions completely ! , I wish I wrote in first line that I know that text is surely located in 38th element of the list

Comment: When you say "the 38th line", are you counting the first line as line 1 or line 0. These silly computers nowadays start at 0, not like us humans.

Comment: I just edit my question and clarifying that there is no indexing problem and also preventing from (more) down vote !

Comment: It might be wise to additionally correct the index you are using to access the line in question if you want to prevent people from being confused.

Comment: @user702846, it's clear to me from your comment to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478931/weird-string-behavior-after-reading-from-text-file-in-python/6478983#6478983) that you are having a unicode problem, not a string indexing problem. I'm upvoting accordingly and encourage others to do the same. But you should put your comment into your answer if you really want people to notice the change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, if it seems like the characters in a string are "too wide", you probably have a unicode file. Try converting it using the [`unicode` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#unicode).

Looking at your code above it looks more like a simple indexing error though.

Comment: ['\x00U\x00n\x00c\x00a\x00l\x00i\x00b\x00r\x00a\x00t\x00e\x00d\x00', '\x00P\x00e\x00a\x00k\x00s\x00:\x00\r\x00\n']
you are right, so how can I change or, modify the entries ro remove these \xooU

Comment: That's not unicode though. Your string is riddled with null characters (the \x00 thingies). I don't know why but it obviously has something to do with the application that writes your file in the first place. The characters are quite easy to get rid of, however:
`nice_string = filter(lambda x: x != '\x00', weird_string)`

Comment: That could, in fact, be Unicode (big-endian UTF-16, specifically).

Comment: I think you'll find `nice_string = weird_string.replace("\x00", "")` is about 8 times faster than your filter + lambda approach.

Comment: kindall and lazyr, you're both right of course. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `contents[37][0]`? The 38th line should be at index 37 since indexes start at 0.

Comment: Some people even don't read other people comments and response and just write some answer to get something, Senderle mention exactly this thing in his comment!! thats the bad side of stack.

Comment: I wouldn't agree that he did. He says that you should have debugged your code and I perfectly agree with him. I, on the other side, tell you that you might have an indexing issue here. Moreover, I haven't seen his comment before adding mine (not that this would have made any difference).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if ind == 38:
   print line
line = line.split()
```

Verify that it is line you want and split it. Like the above poster says, you might be misreading the line too.

Answer (score 0):

```
fd = open('foo.html')
contents = fd.readlines()
fd.close()

for ind, line in enumerate(contents):
    line = line.split(" ")
    contents[ind] = line

print contents,'\n\n------------------'


fd = open('foo.html')
li = fd.readlines()
fd.close()

a = map(lambda x: x.split(" "),li)
print a,'\n',a==contents,'\n\n------------------'


fd = open('foo.html')
b = [line.split(" ") for line in fd]
fd.close()

print b,'\n',b==contents
```